# Tight coupling in application and server due to Auth

Tags: android, ios, oauth, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I have to design a native mobile app which uses `Access token` with expiry time as 2 min. The application maintains a timer and it asks for new `access token` in every 2 min in background.
I feel this design introduces a tight coupling between the server and the app of maintaining 2 mins time. In an ideal world, maintaining the life of `access token` shouldn't be applications responsibility. Am I missing something in the design? 
Is there any tutorial where communications between App and server is specified when  using `OAuth`?

Comment: Normally you wouldn't proactively refresh the token.  When you need to make a request you check for token expiry and refresh it if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have the access token timeout hardcoded in your application. You get it in the `expiresIn` response attribute from the `/token` endpoint. For more info, see the [OAuth2 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.4).

As Paulw11 mentioned, it's not necessary to refresh the access token proactively. You can design your HTTP client the way takes both tokens (access and refresh token) and the access token expiration time as parameters and refreshes the access token if necessary before using it.

I'm not sure what you mean by "communications between App and server", but there is an RFC about [OAuth2 for native apps](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252).